# Haskell: Difficulty embedding the context (Eq a) into a data declaration

Tags: haskell

I am writing a simple hash tree structure in the following program `hash_lookup.hs`:

```
module Main where

    data (Eq a) => HashTable a b = HashChildren (a, [HashTable a b]) | Hash (a, b) deriving (Show)

    getKey :: HashTable a b -> a

    getKey (HashChildren (k, hs)) = k
    getKey (Hash (k, h)) = k

    lookUp :: [a] -> HashTable a b -> Maybe (HashTable a b)

    lookUp [] table = return table
    lookUp _ (Hash _) = Nothing
    lookUp (p:path) (HashChildren (_, ts) ) = lookUp path ( head ( dropWhile (\x -> (getKey x) /= p) ts ) )
```

getKey is intended to retrieve the root key of a given HashTable, and lookUp takes a list of strings and is meant to follow the first path it finds until it either reaches the full path or fails (I'm aware that this isn't natural behaviour for a tree but it's what my tutorial wants).

I have two questions:
1) Why do I get an error message telling me that `a /= a` (from the final line) is not allowed as there is `No instance for (Eq a)` (the error message in terminal), despite `(Eq a)` in the data declaration?

2) Other than the error I'm getting and the seemingly strange behaviour of the lookup function, is this *good* or *idiomatic* Haskell?

Thanks

Comment: The datatype context feature is going to be removed in future version of Haskell http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2011-January/022497.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the common "gotchas" in Haskell is that if you put class constraints on a `data` declaration, **every** function that uses the type must have the class constraints too.  For this reason, your `data` declaration is not idiomatic in Haskell, and you should eliminate its class constraint.  It doesn't gain you anything to declare the class constraint in the `data` declaration anyway.

Basically, function types **must** repeat the class constraint.  How else is a user of the function to know that they must use an instance of the classes in question?  Notice that you can have a function `f` defined in terms of a function `g` defined in terms of an `h` that's defined in terms of your `HashTable a b` type, such that `f` doesn't mention your `HashTable` type at all, yet because of the type dependencies it takes an argument of type `a` that indirectly and ultimately is used as the first parameter of your `HashTable` type.  `f`'s type **must** have the class constraint, Haskell correctly infers so, and it will reject your type annotations if they lack it.

Comment: Notice that the very latest language standard outright removed datatype contexts.